# Eclipse RCP app: How to disable specific extensions?

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I'm using Eclipse HELIOS to code a Rich Client app.
The following entries are added automatically to my APP "PERSPECTIVES MENU":
"Java, Java Browsing, Java Type Hierarchy, Team Synchronizing".
I need to get rid of them.

i'm using the extension point="org.eclipse.ui.activities" to disable unwanted extensions (like the editor and search options that appear on the coolbar)

I managed to get rid of "Debug" by adding "org.eclipse.debug.ui.*"

This is my actual config:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
    <activity id="rcpcolibri.disablextensions" name="Hidden activities"/>
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="rcpcolibri.disablextensions" pattern="org.eclipse.debug.ui.*"/>
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="rcpcolibri.disablextensions" pattern="org.eclipse.search.*"/>
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="rcpcolibri.disablextensions" pattern="org.eclipse.ui.editors.*"/>
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="rcpcolibri.disablextensions" pattern="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.*"/>
</extension>
```

What extensions should I disable?

Is there another way of managing this issue?

Eclipse should work the other way arround: we shoud ADD what we need, and not have everything thrown in by eclipse...

Comment: "org.eclipse.team.*" was responsible for "Team Synchronizing". It's now gone from the Perspective menu. Still looking for the "Java..." options.

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution for this? Seems odd that we would have to explicitly disable these views

Answer (score 2):

What template did you follow to create your RCP?
If you look at [Vogella's RCP tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html), you end up with a very empty RCP:

[image]

That being said, Vogella also addresses activities in his "[Eclipse Activities – Hide / Display certain UI elements](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2009/07/13/eclipse-activities/)", where you can see concrete  example of `activityPatternBinding` filtering.
He recommends also to combine those activities with some [commands](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCommands/article.html#commmands_sourceprovider).

> Activities can also be used together with core expressions and your own define expressions (which you define via `ISourceProvider`.

Comment: I used "create new Plugin-Project" with the Rich Client App Option. I've configured everything, and ALL was working as it should until the latest eclipse Helios Auto-Update. After that, my Perspective Menu was "invaded" with new options.