# How to remove default things(functionalities) present in the IDE which was created using eclipse plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I m doing a eclipse plugin project to create an IDE for a particular language using java.
I have almost completed the IDE,but when i created the setup file for that using the "export the eclipse product" option in the eclipse the things of eclipse such as menu items,toolbar items,some views are also present in my IDE which is not necessary for the IDE for that particular Language.How to remove these things from my IDE and keep only the items which i have created.

How shall i do this?
Can anyone help me in doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined which plugins should be in your product. See your `.product` file in the `Dependencies` section. You should try to delete all plugins and just add your own one. Then disable `Include optional dependencies` and click `Add required Plug-ins`. Are there now less Plug-Ins than before?

Maybe this link is interesting for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4057122/714965

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't remove other plug-ins. You will either need to build the whole thing from sources or create temporary install somewhere, run it, install your plugin there, remove any plugins that you don't want, zip it and distribute that.

Comment: how to remove the plugins which i dont need?
U mean to say i need to run my plgin by installing the plugin in the eclipse plugins folder?

Comment: Select "about eclipse" and there "installation details". You will see an option to remove plug-ins. You can install your plugin by simply copying it or by creating eclipse update site and installing from there.

Comment: but the requirement given is not to embed my plugin into the eclipse product.It should be a seperate one,hence I defined a product for my plugin and eported it the problem is the things in the eclipse r also coming.what to do for that?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. Possibly this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056957/eclipse-rcp-app-how-to-disable-specific-extenstions